# How can I display an alias column based on a date condition using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a library database that I am using. The database contains 5 tables as shown below. I am using MS SQL server management studio

[image: Database diagram for library database]

I am currently displaying the bookId, the book name, the author of the book, the book page count, and points from the book table using the following code.

```
select  
    books.bookId,  
    books.name,  

    authors.surname, 

    types.name, 

    books.pagecount, 
    books.point  
from books 
    join authors 
    on books.authorId = authors.authorId 
    join types 
    on books.typeId = types.typeId
```

However, I am also required to display a status column of either `available` or `out` based on the following logic

```
IF borrows.takenDate < current_timeStamp 
AND borrows.broughtDate = null
THEN display status = Out (in status alias column)
ELSE display status Available (in status alias column)
```

This logic has to be added to the SQL statement mentioned prior in the post.

How would I go about doing this in SQL?

Thank you for the assistance :)

Comment: Oh sorry, should have mentioned that MS SQL server management studio

Comment: It currently is a greater than operator

Comment: No, the student cannot reserve the book. Do you believe my logic is incorrect?

Comment: I understand, would you say the logic should rather be "IF borrows.takenDate < current_timeStamp"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like borrows is an associative (junction) table between books and students and could have multiple records of taken/returned, you'll want to get the `MAX` taken date for each unique bookId in a subquery, and join this to your outer query, you can then use a `CASE` statement to check if the subquery bookId is null, if so, this means the book is Available else it's checked Out:

```
select  
    books.bookId,  
    books.name,  

    authors.surname, 

    types.name, 

    books.pagecount, 
    books.point
    --Use case expression to see if subquery bookId is null on join
    --if so, it's available else it's checked out
    case when t.bookId is null then 'Available' else 'Out' end as [status]
from books 
join authors 
on books.authorId = authors.authorId 
join types 
on books.typeId = types.typeId 
left join --subquery returns bookId's for all books currently checked out
(
    select bookId
    from borrows
    where takenDate < current_timestamp and broughtDate is null
    group by bookId, takenDate
    having takenDate = max(takenDate)   
) as t
on t.bookId = books.bookId
```

Comment: @CameronVanRooyen You're quite welcome. If you have any questions about the query, please ask.

Comment: Quick question, why do you use having takenDate = max(takenDate). Im basically asking how it works.

Comment: @CameronVanRooyen This is to eliminate other records of the book being checked out in case there would be another record of a checkout where the `broughtDate is null` and to also ensure you are looking at the most recent checkout record for each book respectively

Comment: Aside: SQL Server supports a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) _expression_, but there is no `case` _statement_.